# How to return the json object instead of redirection after the successful authorization

Tags: php, symfony

How can I get a json object being returned after the successful authorization instead of redirecting to the default path? I'm using Symfony 3.0.1 and I don't use FOSBundle.

My login controller looks like this:

```
class ClientLoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $form   = $this->createForm(ClientLoginType::class, $client);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        $lastEmail = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            return new JsonResponse(
                array(
                    'message' => 'Success! You're authorised!',
                    'result'  => $this->renderView('SymfonyBundle::client/success.html.twig')
                ), 200);
        }

        return $this->render(
            'SymfonyBundle::security/security.html.twig',
            array(
                'login_form' => $form->createView(),
                'error'         => $error,
                'last_email' => $lastEmail,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

And the login part in security.yml config looks like this:

```
form_login:
    login_path: login
    check_path: login
    username_parameter: _email
    failure_forward: false
    default_target_path: login
    csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you post the login form to the URL set as `check_path` in the security config, symfony will intercept the request by a listener and handle user authentication internally and than redirect to a page based on the configuration. The code inside `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())` will never be called actually because of this.

You have multiple options to override this behaviour:

- create an [authentication listener](http://www.webtipblog.com/create-authentication-listener-symfony-2/), listening on `AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS` and `AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE` [events](http://symfony.com/doc/3.0/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events)
- create an [authentication handler](http://www.webtipblog.com/adding-an-ajax-login-form-to-a-symfony-project/)
- create a [custom authentication system](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/guard-authentication.html)

The linked [blog post](http://www.webtipblog.com/adding-an-ajax-login-form-to-a-symfony-project/) above for the authentication handler case is exactly what you need. I just copy paste the code here, you can find more details in the post.

Create the handler class:

```
// AuthenticationHandler.php

namespace path\to\your\class;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;

class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    private $router;
    private $session;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @author  Joe Sexton <joe@webtipblog.com>
     * @param   RouterInterface $router
     * @param   Session $session
     */
    public function __construct( RouterInterface $router, Session $session )
    {
        $this->router  = $router;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * onAuthenticationSuccess
     *
     * @author  Joe Sexton <joe@webtipblog.com>
     * @param   Request $request
     * @param   TokenInterface $token
     * @return  Response
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess( Request $request, TokenInterface $token )
    {
        // if AJAX login
        if ( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ) {

            $array = array( 'success' => true ); // data to return via JSON
            $response = new Response( json_encode( $array ) );
            $response->headers->set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );

            return $response;

        // if form login 
        } else {

            if ( $this->session->get('_security.main.target_path' ) ) {

                $url = $this->session->get( '_security.main.target_path' );

            } else {

                $url = $this->router->generate( 'home_page' );

            } // end if

            return new RedirectResponse( $url );

        }
    }

    /**
     * onAuthenticationFailure
     *
     * @author  Joe Sexton <joe@webtipblog.com>
     * @param   Request $request
     * @param   AuthenticationException $exception
     * @return  Response
     */
     public function onAuthenticationFailure( Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception )
    {
        // if AJAX login
        if ( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ) {

            $array = array( 'success' => false, 'message' => $exception->getMessage() ); // data to return via JSON
            $response = new Response( json_encode( $array ) );
            $response->headers->set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );

            return $response;

        // if form login 
        } else {

            // set authentication exception to session
            $request->getSession()->set(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);

            return new RedirectResponse( $this->router->generate( 'login_route' ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Register it as a service and set is as the success and failure handler of the used firewall:

```
# Resources/config/services.yml

acme.security.authentication_handler:
        class: path\to\your\class\AuthenticationHandler
        public: false
        arguments:
            - @router
            - @session

# app/config/security.yml

security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                check_path:      security_check_route
                success_handler: acme.security.authentication_handler
                failure_handler: acme.security.authentication_handler
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Creating an authentication handler seemed comprehensive to me :)

Comment: @rvaliev if you find this answer to be what you were looking for, please accept it :)

Comment: If you use symfony 5 its enough to specify the full class name of the AuthenticationHandler in security.yaml e.g. like this:   failure_handler: 'App\Authentication\AuthenticationHandler'